# Copy formula from [1,X] range to [Y,X] range with relative reference

Tags: excel, vba

I have two named ranges, the `Source` G3:M3, and the `Target` G8:M10.

The `Source` contains a formula that references a cell outside the range on the same row. I want to copy it in the target range, as shown in the picture.

[image: setup]

I wrote the following routine

```
Sub CopyFormulas()

TargetRangeName = "Target"
SourceRangeName = "Source"

Range(TargetRangeName).Clear

Range(TargetRangeName).Formula = Range(SourceRangeName).Formula

End Sub
```

The formula is copied in the range, but the relative references are not modified correctly, giving the result shown in the picture.

[image]

The relative reference starts at row 3 instead of at the first row of the `Target` range.

A couple of solutions that are not applicable in my case:

- copy and paste would yield the correct result, but this routine is to be repeated thousands of times therefore performance is critical, and the performance improvement using assignment is 10 fold
- change the formula to have the reference in the correct position, which is not applicable since I am working with a large, complex and old file, where changing hundreds of formulas is not feasible, and `Target` could change position relative to `Source`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by setting the `.FormulaR1C1` property instead of the `.Formula` property. Like this:

```
Public Sub ClientCode()
    Dim srcRng As Range
    Dim tarRng As Range

    Set srcRng = Range("Source")
    Set tarRng = Range("Target")

    tarRng.Formula2R1C1 = srcRng(1).Formula2R1C1
End Sub
```

`.FormulaR1C1` maintains the relative references

Comment: Hi, it does not work. It works for the first row and then the relative reference is moved down by 2 rows. https://anonfile.com/F9z4t9Ofnc/Schermata_2020-01-19_alle_21.45.53_png

Comment: Revision - hmm doesn't seem to work in this specific case.

Comment: What about using this for the first row, then expanding with `Range.Expand`

Comment: The range is set in another routine and needs to be set before for separate reasons. I am curious though of why it yields this wierd behavior of increasing the reference by 2 cells.

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious that is the Word Object Model - maybe you mean `Resize`?

Comment: @FrancescoZaffaroni it would be helpful if I could see a sheet with source range populated with the source formula and the target range populated with the desired formulas

Comment: @Bigben absolutely correct.  Thank you for catching that.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize

Comment: @FrancescoZaffaroni - the weird behavior is because when you write the `.FormulaR1C1`, the 1st row's formula is `=R3C*RC5`, which is correct, but the 2nd row is `=R3C*R[1]C5`.

Comment: @FrancescoZaffaroni anonfile is being too sketchy for me to trust downloading from it

Comment: @ArcherBird https://www.dropbox.com/s/e21zhaeaddn4afe/vbacopyformula.xlsb?dl=0 here is a dropbox link. If you prefer I can save as a plain xlsx and remove the macro

Comment: @FrancescoZaffaroni thanks, it’s not you I don’t trust, just the anon site. I got your file and I’m taking a look :-)

Comment: @FrancescoZaffaroni I have amended my answer to use only the first cell of the source range as the source for the formula copy. This seams to be working.

Comment: @BigBen - just noticed your "go bucks". It was an exciting year with a sad finish :-(

Comment: @ArcherBird It seems to be working for me too. I would just need to check if in the actual file all the formulas are the same. Would be able to expand on why copying only the first cell has it working in your opinion? In order to have a complete answer for future visitors. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @FrancescoZaffaroni - I must admit, I've been a little baffled by this myself. First thing to note is that calling `.Formula` on a Range of multiple cells actually returns an array of strings, whereas the same call on a Range of a single cell will return a string. So the copying of only the first cell works because you are assigning a single string value into an array of formulas. This has the affect of setting each element in the array to that string. I imagine something weird is going on behind the scenes when you try to assign an array of formulas with a difference sized array of formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Your macro is copying the string, essentially a defacto absolute reference.  You would get the same behavior it you manually copied a formula from inside the formula bar and pasted it inside the formula bar if another cell.

You say this is a "large, complex and old file, where changing hundreds of formulas is not feasible, and Target could change position" but you don't want to use `Copy`.  Hate to break it to you, you can't have it both ways.  Either update the source, or copy it.

`Range(SourceRangeName).Copy Range (TargetRangeNamw)`

You might be able to save some CPU cycles by removing `Range.Clear`, it may not truly be necessary.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. What puzzles me is that the second and third rows in the range have the formula updated, but starting from the wrong reference., anyway copy/paste is not a solution here.

Comment: Unfortunately to make sure the results are correct `Range.Clear` is necessary, and not that impactful to the performance. Thanks!